# Remove all non-ASCII characters from string

Tags: c#, ascii

I have a C# routine that imports data from a CSV file, matches it against a database and then rewrites it to a file. The source file seems to have a few non-ASCII characters that are fouling up the processing routine.

I already have a static method that I run each input field through but it performs basic checks like removing commas and quotes. Does anybody know how I could add functionality that removes non-ASCII characters too?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
string sOut = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s))
```

Comment: Important to note that using asciiencoding will replace all non-ascii characters with '?'(63), which may or may not be what you want or expect.

Comment: furthermore, you can check if it contains only ASCII, if `s == sOut`

Answer (score 59):

Here a simple solution:

```
public static bool IsASCII(this string value)
{
    // ASCII encoding replaces non-ascii with question marks, so we use UTF8 to see if multi-byte sequences are there
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(value) == value.Length;
}
```

source: http://snipplr.com/view/35806/

Comment: This solution has the benefit of working in portable class libraries, where Encoding.ASCII is not available.

Comment: It also has the benefit of being a lot faster than the accepted solution because it does not need to actually create an encoded string.

Comment: -1; the question asked for "functionality that removes non-ASCII characters", which this doesn't do. The *title* was ambiguous, but the solution to that is to clarify the title (which I've done), not to answer a question that the OP didn't ask. This might be a good answer to a different question than the one you've posted it on, but is a non-answer to the one you did.

Comment: you are genius!

Answer (score 15):

Do it all at once

```
public string ReturnCleanASCII(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    foreach(char c in s)
    {
       if((int)c > 127) // you probably don't want 127 either
          continue;
       if((int)c < 32)  // I bet you don't want control characters 
          continue;
       if(c == ',')
          continue;
       if(c == '"')
          continue;
       sb.Append(c);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I would want tab, line feed and carriage return (9, 10, 13), so I just added `if ((int)c == 9 || (int)c == 10 || (int)c == 13)` as the first if and append it.

Answer (score 8):

If you wanted to test a specific character, you could use

```
if ((int)myChar <= 127)
```

Just getting the ASCII encoding of the string will not tell you that a specific character was non-ASCII to begin with (if you care about that).  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

Here's an improvement upon the accepted answer:

```cs
string fallbackStr = "";

Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.ASCII.CodePage,
  new EncoderReplacementFallback(fallbackStr),
  new DecoderReplacementFallback(fallbackStr));

string cleanStr = enc.GetString(enc.GetBytes(inputStr));
```

This method will replace unknown characters with the value of `fallbackStr`, or if `fallbackStr` is empty, leave them out entirely.  (Note that `enc` can be defined outside the scope of a function.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds kind of strange that it's accepted to drop the non-ASCII.

Also I always recommend the excellent [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) library for parsing CSV-files.

Answer (score 1):

```
strText = Regex.Replace(strText, @"[^\u0020-\u007E]", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string RunCharacterCheckASCII(string s)
    {
        string str = s;
        bool is_find = false;
        char ch;
        int ich = 0;
        try
        {
            char[] schar = str.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < schar.Length; i++)
            {
                ch = schar[i];
                ich = (int)ch;
                if (ich > 127) // not ascii or extended ascii
                {
                    is_find = true;
                    schar[i] = '?';
                }
            }
            if (is_find)
                str = new string(schar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return str;
    }
```