# String.Replace not replacing apostrophe

Tags: c#, string, replace

I'm trying to replace apostrophes with a string, for some reason the method just doesn't find the apostrophe in the string. Here is the URL that just doesn't seem to work:

```
"/news/2012/march/cameron’s-crackdown-on-whiplash-–-why-the-minimum-speed-requirement-is-oddly-suspicious"
.Replace("'", "&apos;");
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are you definate you are assigning the value back to the string? .Replace on its own doesnt save the value back to the original string

Comment: Check the font in your question's `code`. You can see it's a different character, there are apostrophes, single quotes, (back)ticks...

Comment: The problem is that `'` does not equal `’`.

Comment: You don't show what you are doing with the string. Are you expecting the string to change, or do you realise `String.Replace` returns a new string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# string replace does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277667/c-sharp-string-replace-does-not-work)

Comment: You are probably looking for the [`WebUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388360.aspx) class (`HtmlEncode`/`HtmlDecode` methods), or [`HttpUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90d18ktz(v=vs.85).aspx) if you are targeting older .NET framewords. There is no reason to HTML-encode all these chars manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable types. You can't change them. Even if you think you change them, you ***create a new strings object***. [`String.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method also returns a new string by the way.

Try to assign in a new string reference with `"’"` not `"'"`.

```
string str = "/news/2012/march/cameron’s-crackdown-on-whiplash-–-why-the-minimum-speed-requirement-is-oddly-suspicious".Replace("’", "&apos;");
```

Answer (score 9):

The replace doesn't work because `’` and `'` are not the same character.

And maybe you forgot to capture the result, your code is too short to tell.

Comment: +1 this is the answer (assuming OP understands that Replaces returns new string).

Answer (score 5):

`’` and `'` are different characters. You also need to assign it somewhere (strings are immutable), `Replace()` returns new string:

```
myString = myString.Replace("’", "&apos;");
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is one of these characters not on my keyboard. I tried using replace to enter somoe text into a sql database and the character it was failing on was    ˈ    and not '  . Is there a different wa of handling this that can catch all of them without copying and pasting this ˈ character into code or is that the only way? I'd never come across this before but the ˈ  was after a schwa.

Comment: @user609926 I don't understand (how you're trying to replace sql). Post a question with source code.

Answer (score 3):

Since strings are immutable, you need to assign your result back to another string.

```
string original = "/news/2012/march/cameron’s-crackdown-on-whiplash-–-why-the-minimum-speed-requirement-is-oddly-suspicious";
string updated = original.Replace("’","&apos;");
```

(note also that ` and ’ are not the same)

Answer (score 1):

Your are replacing `'` instead of `’`. Also remember that strings are immutable, so you must assign the result to a new variable in case you want to store it.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the result to a variable

```
var str = "...".Replace("'", "&apos;");
```