# String.Replace() is not working as expected to replace weird chars in strings in C#

Tags: c#, replace

I have a string **DisplayName** which has value as "**Vinny' Direct Reports**". I am trying to replace "**'**"with "**-**"in string as it failing to get ingested into my Data Source.

Below is the code where I am trying to replace.

```
if (DisplayName.Contains("'", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
        {
            DisplayName.Replace("'", "-").Replace("\"", "-");
            Console.WriteLine(DisplayName);
        }
```

Comment: Replace returns a string, so you will need to assign the output back to your variable

Comment: I just realized that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442577/string-replace-not-replacing-apostrophe already has answer. Thanks a ton. I am good now.

Comment: @LarsTech Why is `Replace` not a method? Saying that `Replace` is not a method seems wrong even with a very conservative view of the defintions of two terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
DisplayName.Replace("'", "-").Replace("\"", "-");
```

To this:

```
DisplayName = DisplayName.Replace("'", "-").Replace("\"", "-");
```

Comment: I just realized that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442577/string-replace-not-replacing-apostrophe already has answer. Thanks a ton. I am good now.