# replacing string using extension method

Tags: c#, .net

If I have string and I want to replace last character from that string with star for example.

I tried this

```
var myString = "ABCDEFGH";
myString.ReplaceCharacter(mystring.Length - 1, 1, "*"); 

public static string ReplaceCharacter(this string str, int start, int length, string replaceWith_expression)
{
    return str.Remove(start, length).Insert(start, replaceWith_expression);
}
```

I tried to use this extension method but this doesn't work.
Why this doesn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# string replace does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277667/c-sharp-string-replace-does-not-work)

Answer (score 8):

The method, as it is, replace the character, but you have to catch the result

```
myString = myString.ReplaceCharacter(myString.Length - 1, 1, "*");
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that strings are immutable. The methods replace, substring etc do not change the string itself. They create a new string and replace it. So for the above code to be correct it should be

```
myString = myString.ReplaceCharacter(myString.Length - 1, 1, "*");
```