# Replace part of a JSON with other (using a string token)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm having an issue that I cant fix, I seek and seek in different places, but I still without find it.

See this code:

```
//I have 2 json to merge  

var json = @"{'client': {'name': 'Should NO CHANGE', 'lastname': '', 'email': 'asd@asd.com', 'phone': '',  'birthday': '', 'married': false, 'spouse': {'name': '', 'lastname': ''} } }";

var json2 = @" {'client': {'name': 'aaaa', 'lastname': 'bbbb', 'email': 'cccccc@ccccc.com',  'phone': '', 'birthday': '', 'married': false,  'spouse': {'name': 'dddddd', 'lastname': 'eeeee'} } } ";

//for example to properties to replace
var path = "client.spouse";
var path2 = "client.email";

dynamic o1 = JObject.Parse(json);
dynamic o2 = JObject.Parse(json2);



//I want this, but using the string (LIKE REFLECTION) 
// NOT THE DYNAMIC object 
// Can be a simple property or a complex object
o1.client.spouse = o2.client.spouse;
o1.client.email = o2.client.email;
```

I need to use a string instead of "o1.client.email" to replace the content. Because can be anything. (also the json can be anything)

I can replace by strings, by dynamic, or whatever it work.

(XML works, but I lost the data type when is a date, boolean or numeric)

Example in [NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rmUG0F).

Comment: Does `String.Replace` work?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman it is well known that [String replace does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277667/c-sharp-string-replace-does-not-work) :)

Comment: I don't understand the question well, but if you want to replace `client.email` with a string, `o1.client.email = "yourString";` works.

Comment: `o1["client"]["email"]`? [JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) and [JToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Item.htm).

Comment: No, is not the idea, can be any object, not only a string

Comment: o1["client"]["email"] for this, I dont know how many levels or object can I have.

Comment: Your english is very hard to understand. I hope you don't take this negatively as it's still impressive for non native speaker.

Comment: Are you looking for `o1.client.email = o2.SelectToken("client.email");` ?

Comment: close, but o1.client.email should be a string like o1["client.email"]

Comment: So you want something like xpath but for Json instead of xml?

Comment: Exactly that. Its possible ?

Comment: [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) and [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) support [JSONPath queries](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), I assume that's why @BrianRogers suggested it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to select any item in the JSON object hierarchy.  It supports [JSONPath query syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).  It returns a `JToken` corresponding to the *value* of the selected item, or `null` if not found.  That `JToken` in turn has a [`Replace(JToken replacement)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Replace.htm) method.  Thus you can do:

```
var o1 = JObject.Parse(json);
var o2 = JObject.Parse(json2);

var path = "client.spouse";
o1.SelectToken(path).Replace(o2.SelectToken(path));

var path2 = "client.email";
o1.SelectToken(path2).Replace(o2.SelectToken(path2));
```

Comment: This was exactly what I need ! VERY VERY THANKS !

Comment: Note, be careful as this only works if the item exists.  If the item does not exist, `SelectToken` returns null and you'll need to change your strategy.