# Querying JSON using SelectTokens? With Newtonsoft.Json.Linq in C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I'm trying to make use of Netwonsoft.JSON.Linq in C#, to change the "statusCode" values in the following JSON:

```
{  
   "disbursements":[  
      {  
         "id":"1f337641",
         "contactId":"f5eb2",
         "statusCode":166000005,
         "amount":8,
         "category":166000001
      },
      {  
         "id":"027a4762",
         "contactId":"f5eb2038",
         "statusCode":166000000,
         "amount":4000,
         "category":166000000
      }
   ]
}
```

So, inside the JSON data is: "disbursements" which is JSON array. I have to change the "statusCode" of each item in the array to `166000005`. I'm able to retrieve statusCode of the first one using

```
JObject jsonText = JObject.Parse(bodyText);
var statusCode = (int)jsonText.SelectToken("disbursements[0].statusCode");
```

But I need a solution with loop or LINQ that changes all the values, not just the first.

Comment: 1) Could you please [edit] your question to provide a valid JSON sample?  Your current JSON fails validation at https://jsonlint.com/.  Maybe you just need outer braces `{` and `}`?  2) You wrote, *I'm able to retrive statusCode by 'disbursement[0]["statCode"]'*.  Can you show what you tried and why it doesn't work, so we don't have to guess and provide an answer you don't need?  See [ask].

Comment: This isn't valid JSON but why cant you just loop over your object Newtonsoft deserialized for you?

Comment: Is this what you want?  [Replace Part of a Json with Other (using a string token) C# , Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33056210/3744182).

Comment: I want to just change statusCode value to '166000008'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code sets or adds `"statusCode": 166000005` to every entry in the disbursement array:

```
var jsonText = JObject.Parse(bodyText);
foreach (var disbursement in jsonText.SelectTokens("disbursements[*]"))
{
    disbursement["statusCode"] = 166000005;
}
```

Notes:

- The query string `"disbursements[*]"` contains the [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) wildcard operator `[*]`.  This operator matches all array elements under the parent element `"disbursement"`.

  Json.NET supports JSONPath syntax as documented in [Querying JSON with JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).
- [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) is used rather than `SelectToken()` to loop through multiple possible matches.
- The `JToken` [item setter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Item.htm) `disbursement["statusCode"] = 166000005` will replace the `"statusCode"` property if present and add it if not.
- A simple, atomic value such as `166000005` can be set directly into a `JToken` hierarchy.  For a complex POCO you would need to call [`JToken.FromObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) to serialize it to a `JToken` before setting it in the hierarchy, e.g.:

  ```
  disbursement["statusCode"] = 
      JToken.FromObject( new { oldValue = disbursement["statusCode"], newValue = 166000005 } );
  ```

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xBBlWw).

Answer (score 0):

I would create classes to represent the data. Here is my solution:

Create the data holder classes:

```cs
public class Disbursement
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contactId")]
    public string ContactId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("statusCode")]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("category")]
    public int Category { get; set; }
}
```

The collection:

```cs
public class Disbursements
{
    [JsonProperty("disbursements")]
    public List<Disbursement> Items { get; set; } = new List<Disbursement>();
}
```

And then the loading / modifying / saving data:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var disbursements =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Disbursements>(
                File.ReadAllText(
                    "data.json",
                    Encoding.UTF8
                )
            );

        foreach (var disbursement in disbursements.Items)
        {
            disbursement.StatusCode = 166000005;
        }

        string modifiedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(disbursements);

        File.WriteAllText(
            "modifiedData.json",
            modifiedContent,
            Encoding.UTF8
        );
    }
}
```