# Update Json file as a function c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So I have a program that has to constantly update different values of different Json files. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json, and I know I can modify a Json file as follows:

```
jsonObject["Object1"]["Object2"]["key"] = "new value";
```

This works great, but I'd hate to have to list all different possibilities, and basically have a function for each different location. I was trying to create a function that could take the value path as an array of strings kind of like this:

```
string[] valueJsonPath = { "Object1", "Object2", "key"}
```

I thought I would be able to use a for loop to get the right JToken, and then just modify that. However this didn't work.

So my question is this: How can I make a function that will take the path to the value as a parameter?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Something like this?  [Replace part of a JSON with other (using a string token)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33045235/3744182).

Comment: Just like that! It worked! I have been looking at the documentation, but I couldn't find anything!

Comment: Glad that worked.