# JToken set Value - JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I am trying to set a value for a jtoken I am retreiving from the below json

```
{
  "Customer":
    {
      "Id": "100",
      "Country": "BE",
      "CustomerName": "Domo",
      "CustomerStatus": "Gold",
      "CreationDate": {
         "Time":""
      }
    }
 }
```

I am managing to retrieve the token for time using the following jPath:

Customer.CreationDate.Time

But getting a null value when trying to set the property:

```
 var property = timeJToken as JProperty;
 property.Value = value;
```

Comment: If you're accessing `Customer.CreationDate.Time` via `SelectToken()`, then be aware that `SelectToken` returns the `JValue` itself, not the `JProperty`.  Thus you need to replace the value using `JToken.Replace(JToken replacement) `.  See [Replace part of a JSON with other (using a string token)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33045235/3744182) for which this might be a duplicate.

Comment: But if not a duplicate, can you please share the code for a [mcve] that demonstrates how you parse your JSON and access the `timeJToken` token?

Comment: @dbc Understood, and it worked!