# How can I change a newline character of a string into a space character

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a string like this:

```
Washington  
Madrid 
Delhi
London
```

And I want to change it to:

```
Washington Madrid Delhi London
```

Replacing the newline characters with space characters.

This is what I tried:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string of cities is recieved from a rich textbox

    String cities;   

    cities = RichTextBox1.Text;


    cities = cities.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");

    RichTextBox1.Clear();
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(cities);
}
```

Comment: Following link is not exact duplicate but contains explanation of well known fact that [C# string replace does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277667/c-sharp-string-replace-does-not-work).

Comment: can you paste the exact text, which you get in richtextbox? you can copy it in debug mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a Regular Expression like this:

```
var joined = Regex.Replace(cities, @"[\r\n]+", " ")
```

This will take into account the fact you have carriage returns (or not), line feeds and spaces (possibly tabs too), making sure the output has exactly one space between each word

Comment: how does this replace a newline character with a space character as the question states?

Comment: @MongZhu quite right, I modified the example to fit the question. It's still worth noting that this approach handles `\r\n` or `\n` which was my intention, just hastily written

Comment: I would also prefer Regex over string `Replace`. missing the question in a hurry happened to me also. I am more fan of commenting than downvoting hastily :)

Answer (score 8):

.Net [string type is immutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/362314fe.aspx). Your code should be,

```
cities = cities.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, " ");
```

Comment: @A Bittersweet Life it is not working in my case. I tried after changing my code according to yours. But it does work in other cases .  like in this case     cities = cities.Replace("q", " ");

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because you have to **set** your `cities` object with the `Replace` function like this:

```
cities = ...Your code...
```