# LINQ ignoring where clause with method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I need to add where clauses to my query if the user provides input for those values. So far I am trying to use the follow, but the where clause is ignored. By that I mean that only student with the last name starting with Lewis should be returned, but I am not getting that as a result.

```
            var query = db.STUDENT
            .Where(x => x.STUDENT_CHANGE_IND == null);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName)) query.Where(x => x.STUDENT_LAST_NAME.StartsWith("Lewis"));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName)) query.Where(x => x.STUDENT_FIRST_NAME.StartsWith(firstName));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(spridenId)) query.Where(x => x.STUDENT_ID.Contains(spridenId));

        var y = query.Take(10).ToList();
```

The results I get are:

```
Student ID LastName

002 GUAR - HEMAR    
021 GUAR - Citibank SLC 
08092017    DO NOT USE 92 number mess up    
099 GUAR - ChaseJPM 
161 GUAR - WELLSG   
191 GUAR - TERI
```

Comment: `query = query.Where(....` is what you need to do.

Comment: Of course it is - you're not storing the result anywhere.

Comment: It is well known fact that nothing really works in C# - try https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+linq+where+does+not+work or even simple stuff like [C# string replace does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277667/c-sharp-string-replace-does-not-work). :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to say

```
query = query.Where(x => x.STUDENT_LAST_NAME.StartsWith("Lewis"));
```

instead of just

```
query.Where(x => x.STUDENT_LAST_NAME.StartsWith("Lewis"));
```

Comment: Oh, man. Forehead palm. Of course I have to capture the modified value. Thank you!

Comment: @CindyConway Happens to everyone on occasion :)

Answer (score 2):

Where clauses don't stack if they are called in separate operations. You will need to save the new results each time a Where() statement is executed to ensure that you are working with the filtered list.

Your updated logic would look like this:

```
var query = db.STUDENT.Where(x => x.STUDENT_CHANGE_IND == null);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.STUDENT_LAST_NAME.StartsWith("Lewis"));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.STUDENT_FIRST_NAME.StartsWith(firstName));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(spridenId))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.STUDENT_ID.Contains(spridenId));
}

var y = query.Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: edited, thanks @EdPlunkett