# Removing all occurences of '\' from json response string not working

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

- List item

I have a string object such as the following.

```
string mycontent = "\"The time is Valid\"\n"
string tocompare = "The time is Valid"
```

The contents of mycontent are assigned by the following line of code.

```
string mycontent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I want to be able to remove all the `\n` and the `\` and to do that I do the following.

```cs
mycontent.Trim().Replace(@"\","")
```

I am trying to compare the `mycontent` and `tocompare` for equality. But this does not work.

```cs
if (string.Compare(tocompare, mycontent.Trim().Replace(@"\","")) == 0)
{
     //TODO
}
```

For some reason which  I do not know, I am not able to see equal to `0`.

Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using ````mycontent = mycontent.Trim().Replace(@"\","")````

Comment: On top of that, your string [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5465923/11683) actually contain any slashes.

Comment: @GSerg I am not sure what you mean by my string does not have any slashes?

Comment: @Anna I meant that `mycontent` contains `"The time is Valid"<new line>`. It does not contain a slash.

Comment: I am trying to compare this received string with another string which holds "The time is Valid" using the Compare method.

Comment: Please add your comparison so we can try to explain.

Comment: @mortb Just updated the question

Comment: `mycontent` has the text in double quotes and with a new line after it. `tocompare` has the text without quotes and without the new line. Neither string contains slashes. And, now that we see more code, the [originally suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277667/c-sharp-string-replace-does-not-actually-replace-the-value-in-the-string) no longer applies. Now it should be Possible duplicate of [Why does .NET add an additional slash to the already existent slashes in a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5465923/11683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace slash first and then the quote

```
mycontent = mycontent.Trim().Replace(@"\", "").Replace(@"""", "")
```

In your case:

```
if (string.Compare(tocompare, mycontent.Trim().Replace(@"\","").Replace(@"""", "")) == 0)
{
     //TODO
}
```

Comment: As there are no slashes in the string, the only replace that does something is the one that replaces the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There are no actual slash characters in the string you showed. The slashes in the source code are part of the [string literal syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#string-literals), where the `\"` represents just the character `"` (it needs to be escaped to distinguish it from the end of the string) and the `\n` represents a newline.

If you want to remove quotes and newlines from the sides of the string, you can do that with [`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Trim_System_Char___) too:

```
mycontent.Trim('"', '\n')
```

But that’s a bit of a weird thing to do. If this string actually represents some serialized format for the text you want, like JSON or CSV, you should use a parser for that instead. Where did you get it?

Comment: This string is obtained from ```string mycontent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();```

Comment: @Anna: And what’s that response? JSON? (If it’s HTTP, for example, look at its `Content-Type` header as a good signal.)

Comment: yes, that is a json response

Comment: @Anna: Okay, you should use a JSON parser then.

Comment: I am not sure on how to do that. Can you help me?

Comment: @Anna: I can’t, beyond linking to questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c that might be out of date, but if you edit your question to mention that you have a JSON string, you’ll probably get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a text slash to a string, you must type like this.

```
string mycontent = "\\"+"The time is Valid"+"\\"+"\n";
```

To delete slashes

```
mycontent=mycontent.Trim().Replace("\\","");
```