# C# Replace double quotes to decimal value

Tags: c#

```
var txt = "\"";
txt = txt.Replace("\"", "&#034;");
Console.WriteLine(txt);
```

output: **`&quot;`**

need: **`&#034;`**

Is it possible to get the desired result?

Comment: This code does not give that output. Read [ask] and provide a [mre]. Are you using ASP.NET WebForms and a Label, for example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# string replace does not actually replace the value in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277667/c-sharp-string-replace-does-not-actually-replace-the-value-in-the-string)

Comment: and [string.Replace (or other string modification) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var txt = "\"";
txt = txt.Replace("\"", "&#034;");
Console.WriteLine(txt);
```

And check the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0