# "(" and ")" Replace in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, string

So I am trying to replace the characters below from a users input which relates to a SQL column in a table.

Example:
User creates a field called My(first)try. In SQL this comes up as Myfirsttry.

I am currently write code to replace the users input with our and I am stuck.

I have this so far.

```
  itemreplace = itemreplace.Replace("(", "");
```

This however, doesn't do the trick. Thoughts, comments, suggestions?

Comment: So what *does* it do?  What is the result of running that line of code?

Comment: If you did the same thing again for the closing bracket would life be better?

Comment: itemreplace is a string, right? That certainly should work.

Post your actual code. I just tried that in a quick dirty console application and it properly replaces the open parenthesis with an empty string.

Comment: This smells like your asking for a SQL injection attack... Please tell me you aren't trying to clean up input from the user and make a query out of the text...

Comment: Basically an exact duplicate of this question from two days ago (parenthesis and all): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280553/how-do-i-remove-multiple-offending-characters-from-my-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove characters from C# string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411438/remove-characters-from-c-sharp-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option:

```
String itemreplace = new String("My(first)try");
String charsToRemove = new String[] {"(", ")"};
foreach (char c in charsToRemove)
{
    itemreplace = itemreplace.Replace(c, string.Empty);
}
```

Second option:

```
itemreplace = itemreplace.Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the *real-world case* is more complicated, and you're not indicating that, but to handle your example text `My(first)try` you could just chain the `Replace` statements:

```
itemreplace = itemreplace.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");
```

However, it seems like the *real-world* case is more along the lines of leveraging a Regex like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_@#][a-zA-Z0-9@$#_]*$
```

and here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/rK5jL7) that would prove that.

Then using that might look like this:

```
var valid = Regex.IsMatch("My(first)try", pattern);
```

I did reference this post, [What special characters are allowed in T-SQL column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954884/what-special-characters-are-allowed-in-t-sql-column-name), to determine the allowed characters for a column name.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I did try searching but I guess I had no idea what I was searching for to begin with.