# Remove escape character "\" from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, escaping

I need to remove `\` character from `imagepth` string variable:

```
imagepth = "# Eval(\"Name\",\"Gallary/\"" + imgwords[4] + "\"/Images/{0}\")";
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. As far as I can see, imagepth won't contain a single backslash after that assignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove characters from C# string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411438/remove-characters-from-c-sharp-string)

Answer (score 6):

You can use Replace method to replace `"\\"` with a empty string

```
   str = str.Replace("\\", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex Unescape will remove all escaping characters from a string, here is a link to this information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working syntax for me:

```
str = str.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```