# How to replace "0x1B" in a file with nothing ie remove

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC3, C#, .NET 4.5

I need to remove any "Escape" characters which seem to be appearing in a HTML file.

I was trying:

```
NewHtml = OldHtml.Replace("0x1B","")
```

But I think I have something wrong here. Please advise.

Comment: I suspected as such ..... What should the string be?

Comment: The replace is correct but I doubt that your string is right.. Try : `NewHtml  = OldHtml.Replace( ((char)0x1b).ToString(), ""  );`

Comment: You are a star, that sorted it. If you could make this an answer then I will mark it as such. Thanks again. P.S Gosh I remember PB :)

Answer (score 3):

The replace is correct but I doubt that your string is right..

You need to convert the hex value first to a character and then to a string:

`string esc = ((char)0x1b).ToString()`

To remove the one character in your question use :

```
NewHtml = OldHtml.Replace( ((char)0x1b).ToString(), "" );
```

To remove several characters you can do this:

```
var chars = new char[] { (char)27, (char)0x1b, '\t', '~' };
string NewHtml  = OldHtml;
foreach (var c in chars )  NewHtml = str.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty);
```

I have combined a few different ways to create characters.

Or you can, and probably should go for a Regular Expression..

Several other solutions can be found [here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411438/remove-characters-from-c-sharp-string)