# How to remove colon's from a string with in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a string like this "ALTA Homeowner's Policy of Title Insurance". I want to remove colon from above string(which one beside home owner)?
how to do this by using C#

Comment: Are you referring to the `'` character? That is known as an _apostrophe_ or a _single quote_. A _colon_ looks like this: `:`

Comment: There's no colon in your string, but if you want to remove a character from a string, I think this is something you may found on google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove characters from C# string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411438/remove-characters-from-c-sharp-string)

Answer (score 0):

One way is finding the index of colon and then using remove method available for String object.

```
int index;
string s = "ALTA Homeowner's Policy of Title Insurance";
string output;
index = s.IndexOf('\'');
if (index != -1)
{
      output = s.Remove(index, 1);
      Console.Out.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Escape character '\' is used to catch colon.

IndexOf method return the index of first occurance of a matching character.
Other methods like IndexOfAny,LastIndexOf are also available.