# Remove keywords and operators from string expression

Tags: c#

I need you help
I have one string like

a1 + b1 + ( v1 + g1 )  * 10

I need to retrieve only a1,b1,v1,g1
any idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove characters from C# string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411438/remove-characters-from-c-sharp-string)

Comment: What have you already tried? Or should we do all the work that was assigned to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use RegEx to filter the desired output.
Assuming that your result always starts with a small letter and ends with a digit `[a-z][0-9]`

```
string input = "a1 + b1 + ( v1 + g1 ) * 10";
List<string> Result = Regex.Matches(input, @"[a-z][0-9]")
                            .Cast<Match>()
                            .Select(x => x.Value)
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: no dear its not working and also it is giving error on does not contain definition for cast

Comment: add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` and `using System.Linq;`

Comment: what if my string will be like this sss + aaa + AAA + ddd + 10 - www ..this time i would like to retrieve complete string like aaa,AAA

Comment: then reaplce `[a-z][0-9]` with `[a-zA-Z]{3}` for _3 letters_

Answer (score 0):

I'd go after it using a **recursive descent parser**. It may seem as an overkill to start with but it will work for all sorts of expressions.

[Here's a good introduction to the theory.](http://blog.roboblob.com/2014/12/12/introduction-to-recursive-descent-parsers-with-csharp/)