# How to trim unwanted letters from textbox continuously?

Tags: c#, textbox, trim

I am creating a project where the program fetches data from a serial port and displays it in a textbox. But along with the data, some unwanted characters are also getting inputted in the textbox through the serial port. I tried to trim them with '.Trim()' method by adding it in the textchanged event. But I could not get the desired outcome. I want the unwanted letters to get continuously trimmed from the textbox and the method should keep running in the background.
Below is the code I tried out:

```
private void textBoxResults_TextChanged(...)
{
  char[] trim= ['a', 'b'];
  textBoxResults.Text.Trim(trim);
}
```

Please note that those are multiple letters(e.g. they could be g, m, a, etc.)
I want all the unwanted ones to be trimmed from the textbox either directly when serialport data is received or after input from serial port.

Comment: Example data and expected results would help your post.

Comment: `Trim()` doesn’t remove the characters from the string. It removes them from the beginning and the end. It would be better to filter the input before adding it to the text box

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Pls Guide me to do that with some example code and in which event to place it.

Comment: Check if `textBoxResults.Text.Contains("a")`, if so `textBoxResults.Text.Replace("a", string.Empty)` - quick and dirty, you can do it more pretty your self ;)

Comment: Before displaying it in the textbox, clean/scrub the text through a method and display the result in the textbox instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove characters from C# string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411438/remove-characters-from-c-sharp-string)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not exactly what all of you said, but something grouped after googling a bit.

```
string ToBeReplaceCharacters = @"a;b";
foreach(var RepChar in ToBeReplaceCharacters)
{
  textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(RepChar.ToString(), "");
}
```

What Stackloyd said is ok for single character but not multiple characters to be replaced. The above code fulfils my demand.

> Thank You All!

Comment: I think that you can use Regular Expressions for a more elegant and compact solution...

Comment: @Ignotus I was a rookie programmer back then to know much about regex and how easy and compact it is. Now that I have quite some experience with programming, regex is extremely easy and useful!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to iterate to every char to be eliminated if you use Regular Expressions.

```
//Reference to RegularExpressions
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...
//Code omitted...
...

//Put the code in TextChanged event
private void TextBoxResults_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxResults.Text = Regex.Replace(textBoxResults.Text, "[ab]", "");
}
```

The "[ab]" string is a RegEx pattern... 
In this pattern you can put any character or range of characters to be eliminated.

Simple examples:

- "[a-zA-Z]" you will eliminate any alfabetical character
- "[^bla]" you will eliminate any character not equal to 'b', 'l' & 'a'.

Here some other examples of patterns:

```
abc…    Letters

123…    Digits

\d  Any Digit

\D  Any Non-digit character

.   Any Character

\.  Period

[abc]   Only a, b, or c

[^abc]  Not a, b, nor c

[a-z]   Characters a to z

[0-9]   Numbers 0 to 9

\w  Any Alphanumeric character

\W  Any Non-alphanumeric character

\s  Any Whitespace

\S  Any Non-whitespace character
```

More info here:

[Microsoft Regex.Replace reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score -1):

Based solely on the info you provided, my suggestion is to just use

```
textBoxResults.Text = textBoxResults.Text.Replace("<unwanted char>", "")
```

This replaces any *unwanted char* in the string with an empty string, *de facto* deleting them.
Bear in mind that this requires a call to `Replace(...)` for each unwanted character.

Comment: :To which event should I add this?? Is TextChanged ok??

Comment: I think TextChanged is ok. Remember to reassign the result to the TextBox, as `Replace()` does not change the string it is called on, but rather returns a new one: `textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace(...)`. If, for some reason, you specifically want to target text while it's being typed, use KeyUp, but it won't work with copy-pastes.

Comment: Ok. Just be on this question. Ill try thi moment and mark this as answer.