# Removing a certain char from a string that appears over and over

Tags: c#

I have this string:

string ID = 6FA186D2-1246-4691-8560-7BDAC7D10699

And I tried to get rid of the "-", so I went with:

```
    private string FormatProductID()
    {
        return = selectedPackage.id.Trim('-');
    }
```

But this returns only the original string, and doenst alter it at all. I tried using "–" instead of "-" but the result is the same.

Am I using this function wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Trim is for removing whitespaces inside a string, However if you want to remove "-" you could use string.replace("-", string.empty). Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411438/remove-characters-from-c-sharp-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove characters from C# string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411438/remove-characters-from-c-sharp-string)

Comment: That's a common GUID format . It would make more sense to parse it to a Guid with `Guid.Parse` than remove the dashes. It would use *less* memory too - all string operations create new strings. A Guid is 16 bytes

Comment: @yazan: "inside" is a very confusing word to use when describing `Trim`. `Trim` specifically focuses on the **edges** (start/end) of a string.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netcore-3.1) method only removes the characters from the beginning and end.

You are looking for the [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1) method.

```
private string FormatProductID()
{
    return selectedPackage.id.Replace("-","");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Replace

```
private string FormatProductID()
{
    return = selectedPackage.id.Replace("-","");
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty character. You should use strings.

Comment: Thanks @GvS corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You picked the wrong method, try

```
private string FormatProductID()
{
    return selectedPackage.id.Replace("-", string.Empty);
}
```