# how to convert a string with letters to int c#

Tags: c#, string, integer

this is my question:

Input: s = "4193 with words"
Output: 4193

I tryed it this way but it does not work

```
        int a;
         bool  tf =  int.TryParse(s,out a);
        if(tf == true)
        {
            return a;
        }
        return 0;
```

Comment: So you basically want to ignore all non-digits? Would input like "I say 12" yield 12? What  about "12xx34"?

Comment: yes. if the input is 12xx34 then the output should be 1234

Comment: So you have a 2-Step Problem: 1. Strip input string of all non-digit chars. 2. Parse result from 1.) to `int` type. Part 2. you already solved, ... so, we are left with 1.

Comment: Please check that link. I think you can your problem this way.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7411472/13798699

Comment: "Just For Fun"-Alternative: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7wyU5k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to extract only the numeric characters from the string:

```
string numStr = new String(s.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Then use your existing code, but referring to `numStr`:

```
int a;
bool  tf =  int.TryParse(numStr,out a);
if (tf == true)
{
   return a;
}
return 0;
```

Note that if you'd like to support negative integers, you will need to adapt the first part (extracting relevant characters) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i think you search something like this?

```
        string input = "1234 words";
        var outputnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(input, @"\d+").Value);
```