# validate keyboard input for ASCII and special characters

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have textbox in my windows phone 7. I want to validate that user input normal character or some special character or ASCII.

Comment: can please give me an example of your expectation in words

Comment: Yeah Sure. One Min Let Me Do It For You..

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ Here see extended ASCII Codes from 128 code to 175..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done in this way..

```
public int CountChars(string value)
        {
            int result = 0;
            foreach (char c in value)
            {
              if (c>127)
                {
                    result = result + 10; // For Special Non ASCII Codes Like "ABCÀßĆʣʤʥ"
                }

                else
                {
                    result++; // For Normal Characters Like "ABC"
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can determine if the key that is pressed is a letter, digit, or special character by doing the following:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
  {
    // The character is a letter
  }
  else if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
  {
    // The character is a digit
  }
  else
  {
    // The character is a special character
  }
}
```

Comment: Its Not Working.. It Takes ASCII As Letter as well. :)

Comment: If you're wondering on how to determine ascii vs. unicode, then chibacity's answer to this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459571/how-to-recognize-if-a-string-contains-unicode-chars

Comment: I have already done that and put my answer as well. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

simple use a mask text box with a mask!!!

Comment: visual studio has a controler called masked text box.read here =>http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1534/Masked-C-TextBox-Control

Comment: Oups You Are Totally Going In Wrong Direction. I Am Talking About Windows Phone 7 Perceptive. Not Web or Windows Form Base Application. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get data about the text in the textBox:

```
 private void validator(string value, out int letterCount, out int digitCount, out int specialCharCount)
        {
            letterCount=digitCount=specialCharCount=0;
            foreach (char c in value)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetter(c))
                    letterCount++;
                else if (Char.IsDigit(c))
                    digitCount++;
                else
                    specialCharCount++;

            }
        }
```

Call it as:

```
 int a, b, c;
 validator(textBox1.Text, out a, out b, out c);
```

textBox1 is your textBox. It will populate the values of `a,b,c` and using these values you can perform calculations as you desire.