# Contains Unicode Character checking fail

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

```
    public bool ContainsUnicodeCharacter(char[] input)
    {
        const int MaxAnsiCode = 255;
        bool temp;
        string s;

        foreach (char a in input)
        {
            s = a.ToString();
            temp = s.Any(c => c > MaxAnsiCode);

            if (temp == false)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }            
    }
```

This code used to check unicode exist or not on input char array.

I got error message :
" ContainsUnicodeCharacter(char[])': not all code paths return a value"

What went wrong here, Please help.
Thank You.

Comment: **All** .NET `char`s are Unicode characters.

Comment: Well, `s = a.ToString(); temp = s.Any(c => c > MaxAnsiCode);` can be just replaced with `temp = a > MaxAnsiCode;`.

Answer (score 5):

Your method is not well thought through. It can be done much simpler:

```
public static bool ContainsUnicodeCharacter(this IEnumerable<char> input)
{
    const int MaxAnsiCode = 255;
    return input.Any(c => c > MaxAnsiCode);
}
```

You had two nested loops there without reason.

I made the method a generally applicable extension method.

Comment: If you made the parameter `input` have type `IEnumerable<char>`, the method could easily be called with a string or any collection of `char` values. Also, that signature will signal to the callers: "We won't change your `input`, we'll just loop through it."

Comment: This is another solution without using lambda expresions http://stackoverflow.com/a/40252987/348551

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `return true;` just before the last `}`, but I also think you have the test reversed:

```
public bool ContainsUnicodeCharacter(char[] input)
{
    const int MaxAnsiCode = 255;
    bool temp;
    string s;

    foreach (char a in input)
    {
        s = a.ToString();
        temp = s.Any(c => c > MaxAnsiCode); // true if unicode found

        if (temp == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Further to @egrunin's answer, I don't know why you loop through all of the characters and then cast them to a string, just so you can use a Linq method on the resulting character arrayt.  You could simplify your entire method (maintaining the same logic) like this:

```
public bool ContainsUnicodeCharacter(char[] input)
{
    const int MaxAnsiCode = 255;

    return input.Any(c => c > MaxAnsiCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have 1 return statement which is part if a conditional if...as mentioned you can add `return true;` but the reason you got that error is that your function had nothing to return if temp never equated to false

```
public bool ContainsUnicodeCharacter(char[] input)
    {
        const int MaxAnsiCode = 255;
        bool temp;
        string s;

        foreach (char a in input)
        {
            s = a.ToString();
            temp = s.Any(c => c > MaxAnsiCode);
            if (temp == false)
            {
               return false;
             }
        } 
         return true;  
    }
```