# SSIS 2012 - Redirect Rows with Special Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Im using SSIS 2012 and im importing data from a flat file source -> Temp table -> Final table.
Any errors found are redirected to an error File.

However, im tio apply a new constraint that redirecting all rows of a specific column containing special charaters into a separate error file prior inserting it into the temp table.

Im trying to use a conditional split but it creates a case for each specific charaters ,using the Findstring() function.
What are the other options available?

Comment: Can you post a bit of the data you're importing, along with your table structures, and the work you've already done please. It will help people to be able to help you.

Comment: My initial thought at this point is that I would import everything into the temporary table (A), then remove the rows containing the special characters into another temporary table (B), and produce the error file from (B) then update the final table from (A)

Comment: Thanks, based on your suggestion i also though of creating 2 OleDB Command from the soource file with the "like '%-/&%$#%'",  one  will redirect the valid rows to the temp table and the other will redirect the wrong entries to the error file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many specific characters are you going to be dealing with? If it's only a few, you can combine `FINDSTRING()`s together with the `||` "or" operator in the Conditional Split, e.g.:

```
(FINDSTRING( [test_column] , "A", 1) > 0) || (FINDSTRING( [test_column] , "B", 1) > 0) || (FINDSTRING( [test_column] , "C", 1) > 0)
```

would filter rows with test_columns containing "A", "B" or "C" to a single split.

If that's too unwieldy because of the number of characters, then a Script Component, as billinkc suggests is the way to go. (It's especially appropriate if the special characters can be represented as a regualar expression, as script components have access to very good regex functions.)

Comment: The special characters are "-/\$#&*_" .I'll try both approaches

Comment: Cool. Bear in mind that backslash in an escape character in [SSIS string literals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141001.aspx), so you'll need to double it up as "\\" to match it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd look at adding a Script Component into your data flow and have it validate your data.

Add a column called HasJunkData to the output of type boolean (DT_BOOL). If you have multiple things to validate, depending on the level of granularity required, you might want a flag per input column or simply decide at the row level whether its good or bad.

Inside the script itself, I'd use something like [How to recognize if a string contains unicode chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459571/how-to-recognize-if-a-string-contains-unicode-chars) to identify the presence of bad characters or potentially a regular expression depending on what "special characters" means to you.

Comment: I have only one column to validate against a list of pre-defined special characters. Do you have a ressource pointing in using the Script Component with a Flat file (source) and a table(destination). Im fairly new to SSIS.

Comment: There's a [technet example Script Component that redirects rows to a particular output depending on a column value](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136114.aspx) which might help kick you off. (The "REDMOND" redirection example changed to do a different comparison would probably do the trick.)