# Unicode Char Boolean Matching

Tags: c#, char, boolean

I have a problem, a char is being inserted into a Dataset that I am trying to remove before the Dataset is being filled.

I have tried copying the Char and doing a String Match on it. It fails and gets inserted anyway.

The Char is:

also, I have one more:

```
'
```

My string matches:

```
if (KVP.Key != "'")
if (KVP.Key != " ")
```

Where KVP is the `KeyValuePair` in a Dictionary.

The only way I have thought of, to filter and remove is to convert the char's to the Unicode Code and look directly for that. Problem is, I can not find the Unicode Code.

I want to look for something like:

```
U+0061 = 'a'
```

if I use:

```
MessageBox.Show("U+" + char.GetNumericValue('a').ToString());
```

I get:

```
-1
```

then I can find the Char and match. I cannot find the conversion method for this procedure. Do I need a Lookup table with the Unicode Values? Or is there a C# Class already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recognize if a string contains unicode chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459571/how-to-recognize-if-a-string-contains-unicode-chars)

Comment: Thanks but looking for char specific match, not if char is Unicode.

Comment: Maybe it's my browser (IE - at work), but your "The Char is:" and "also, I have one more:" code blocks are useless.  The first is blank and the second is some kind of single-quote thing.  What are you asking?  Are you trying to figure out what the obscure character (that's in a string) that is messing you up?  Iterate through the string and output each of the characters as a 4-digit hex value.  That will give you the Unicode code-point values.

Comment: There is a char in there, it is a blank char, apologies if you have misinterpreted the basis of the post!

Comment: I have the answer: MessageBox.Show(string.Format("U+{0:X4}", Convert.ToByte('a') )); I have to convert to a byte as string format and do a if x == a

Comment: I truly believe editing a Question to suit another's interpretation is a very inadequate  way of resolving issues that the original OP has asked. When data is lost, the Question is no longer the same!

Answer (score 0):

well, it apprars as if a conversion to a byte solves the problem:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("U+{0:X4}", Convert.ToByte('a') ));
```

I get:

```
U+0061
```

So I can now check at a byte to string level:

```
string a = string.Format("U+{0:X4}", Convert.ToByte('a'));
if (a.Equals("U+0061")) throw new Exception("Char Match: " + a);
```

Comment: I would cast the char to int instead. That way all unicode chars will Work. Use:(int)'a'.