# How to disable create a non English text variables in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net

For now, i can write in VS2017:

```
var какаяТоНепонятнаяПеременная = "some variable value here";
```

and VS2017 has compiled it successfully.
I want to allow to write variable names only using letters from the English alphabet.

Comment: Define "English".  What if the variable name is `ghrborpf`?  Is that "English"?

Comment: @David, yes. i want to allow only characters from English alphabet. This question only for characters, var ghrborpf123 is fine.

Comment: In theory, `roslyn` could do this, but I don't know any details.

Comment: They are valid unicode characters, so I don't think you can prevent the compiler from using them.

Comment: You'll probably want to allow _, 0-9, and maybe $, too. And, if you use any kind of code generation or third-party libraries, allow whatever they use-at least where you might create new variables with them. One area of code generation is application settings, but you can probably keep control of that. Maybe a spell-checker approach would work but you'd have to allow approving many jargon words and acronyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how to quickly inject my code into compiler process to force build failure, but that's theoretically feasible. What I can suggest is a workaround with unit tests based on `Roslyn`. The starting point will be an installation of  [Microsoft.Build](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/), [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers), [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) nuget packages. The idea is to load a solution and then a project you want to scan (using `MSBuildWorkpace` api) and iterate through all Documents(files). You asked about validating variable names, so it means you need to detect `IdentifierNameSyntax` items in the `SyntaxTree`, however that's not the only thing you can detect - `MethodDeclarationSyntax`, `ClassDeclarationSyntax` etc. are detectable too. The sample code is below:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Verify_ProjectDoesNotHaveNonASCIICharacters()
    {
        var project = workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects.Single(p => p.Name == "csproj_name");

        foreach (var document in project.Documents)
        {
            var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();

            foreach (var item in semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes())
            {
                switch (item)
                {
                    // you may catch other Syntax types for methods, class names for example
                    case IdentifierNameSyntax identifierName: 
                        Assert.IsFalse(ContainsUnicodeCharacter(identifierName.Identifier.Text), $"Variable {identifierName.Identifier.Text} in {document.Name} contains non ASCII characters");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ASCII character check can be improved, but I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459571/how-to-recognize-if-a-string-contains-unicode-chars) for the sake of time:

```
    private bool ContainsUnicodeCharacter(string input)
    {
        const int MaxAnsiCode = 255;
        return input.Any(c => c > MaxAnsiCode);
    }
```

Some sample code to setup MSBuildWorkspace:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync("...your_path/solution.sln");
```

Comment: Please just call it by the various types of subsets of Unicode because all C# code is Unicode characters. ASCII does not go to 255 and ANSI is not ASCII. (Since you are testing a `char` [UTF-16 code unit] <= 255, the ANSI character set you must be referring to is ISO 8859-1). The question now says "English alphabet" (contrast with letter characters in English text like é and æ), so the range is the letters in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block, or, broadly, like in your code, by .NET Regex `!Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\p{IsBasicLatin}*")`

Comment: Hey @TomBlodget. I agree and I mentioned in the post that validation should be improved. I feel like the question is more about the mechanism of validation rather than about how to filter out characters

Comment: @Artem solutions work fine, but it's didn't work for .net core applications, because of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild nuget package is not working with .netCoreApp :(
Thank you!!!