# How to remove all Unicode (\u8236) characters from a domain name

Tags: c#, unicode

I have domain names being submitted with characters like `\u8236`, but every time it is something else. How can I safely remove all the bad characters without knowing which ones are there?

Comment: Why not encode the url before submission?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recognize if a string contains unicode chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459571/how-to-recognize-if-a-string-contains-unicode-chars)

Comment: `I have domain names being submitted` Why are people submitting domain names to you? To what end?

Comment: I you are getting an http request you should have a separated page for each language.  The language should be in the http header.  Once you know the language than you can apply an encoding associated with the language

Comment: You should read about localized domains. Characters of various charsets should be allowed (there are also top level domains). But before to transmit them, you should translate into "ASCII-like" domain names (and back to display to users). Check how browsers allows such non ASCII domain names.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thank you... yes I already understand that all the localized domains are a major obstacle that prevent me from doing a simple Unicode remove.