# In C#, how to convert to upper case following Unicode rules

Tags: c#, unicode, uppercase

In C#, I want to convert strings to upper case following the rules of Unicode-defined "full case mappings" with no culture-specific tailoring. This means, for example, that `ß` must convert to `SS`.

Both `String.ToUpper()` and `String.ToUpperInvariant()` convert `ß` to `ß`.

Is there a method (built in or third party) that implements this specification?

Someone closed this question claiming it is a duplicate of [Convert a string to ordinal upper or lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466396/convert-a-string-to-ordinal-upper-or-lower-case). I'm afraid they didn't read either question very carefully. That question makes no mention of Unicode standards for case folding. Also, the question has an answer, but it doesn't have a solution, and since 5 years have elapsed, I was hoping there might now be a solution.

Comment: `ß must convert to SS` why? according to wiki  - since 2017 eszett can be capitalized to `ẞ` (U+1E9E ẞ LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S)

Comment: _"That question makes no mention of Unicode standards for case folding"_ - No, but it _does_ mention that .NET simply does not support case-folding, whether or not it follows the Unicode spec is immaterial. I verified that this is still the case in .NET 6 and 7 RC1.

Comment: @IłyaBursov because capital ẞ is very rarely used in German, and is usually written SS in preference. However, that's irrelevant. I want something that conforms to the Unicode standard, whether Unicode got it right or not.

Comment: @Dai my general view is that a question should not be closed as a duplicate of another simply because both questions have the same answer.

Comment: @MichaelKay I think we can respectfully agree-to-disagree on that?

Comment: If the answer, as here, is "it can't be done", then closing all questions having that answer as duplicates would be most unhelpful indeed.