# Unicode characters replace from string using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
string str = "our guests will experience \u001favor in an area";
 bool exists = str.IndexOf("\u001", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;
```

I want to find and replace this characters  \u001 in string.I tried hardly to resolve but still helpless.

Please Resolve this issue. Thanks in advance for your precious help.

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023682/how-do-i-remove-emoji-characters-from-a-string
Not exactly the same problem but still it might be transferable.

Comment: Have you tried? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_

Comment: Also, this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28025891/2889347

Comment: Your string does not contain any `\u001` (whatever that is) character. It contains one `\u001f` character.

Comment: I think you could try something like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522884/remove-all-non-ascii-characters-from-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regexp:

```
var unicodeRegexp = new Regex(@"\x1f");
var testWord = "our guests will experience \u001favor in an area";
var newWord = unicodeRegexp.Replace(testWord, "text for replacement");
```

\x1f is the replacement for \uoo1f, leading zeros should be skipped
https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere, deep inside C# specification, you can find following:

> [Note: The use of the \x hexadecimal-escape-sequence production can be
>   error-prone and hard to read due to the variable number of hexadecimal
>   digits following the \x. For example, in the code:
>
> string good = "\x9Good text";
>
> string bad = "\x9Bad text";
>
> it might appear at first that the leading character is the same (U+0009, a tab character) in
>   both strings. In fact the second string starts with U+9BAD as all
>   three letters in the word "Bad" are valid hexadecimal digits. As a
>   matter of style, it is recommended that \x is avoided in favour of
>   either specific escape sequences (\t in this example) or the
>   fixed-length \u escape sequence. end note]

And also:

> unicode-escape-sequence::
>
> \u hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit
>
> \U hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit hex-digit
>   hex-digit hex-digit

To further simplify, \u is followed by 4 or 8 hex symbols - **not 3**. Your string is interpreted as "our guests will experience **\u001f**avor in an area".

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the C# language specification, [ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf), in section 7.4.2 "*Unicode character escape sequences*", we find

> A Unicode escape sequence represents a Unicode code point. Unicode escape sequences are processed in identifiers (§7.4.3), character literals (§7.4.5.5), and regular string literals (§7.4.5.6). A Unicode escape sequence is not processed in any other location (for example, to form an operator, punctuator, or keyword).
>
> unicode-escape-sequence:: \u hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit
>                                            \U hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit  hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit   hex-digit

So you have to use *four* hex digits with the `\u`.

In your example, it takes "001f" as those four hex digits.

The `"\u001"` in your example should have given an error in Visual Studio along the lines of "Unrecognized escape sequence."